# Have a table in SQL where one column can have multiple values

Tags: sql, relational-database

I am trying to create a table in NetBeans using SQL code and was wondering how you assign multiple items to one column. I have tried using NULL in my insert statement and that doesn't work.

An example of what I mean is having a Retailer only be listed once in the first column but have 3 values in the next column as Items associated to the retailer.

Comment: This is not the way how relational databases work, you have to repeat the Retailer 3 times in the first column with different values in the next column. If the table is indexed by Retailer, the queries are no less efficient.

Comment: Agreed. This doesn't sound like the right application of a relational DB. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to create a table that has two retailers named InfoWare and SoftwareLand. That is my first column so there should only be two values being the retailers. In my  second column I have an Item. Infoware has 3 items and SoftwareLand has 2. Then the third column is Quantity Sold. I am supposed to recreate that table for my class. I agree with you guys it would be way easier to repeat each retailer

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description:

- The database has 2 **retailers**: InfoWare and SoftwareLand
- Each retailer has one or more **items**
- An item tracks how many times it has been sold

... building a database with a single table and multiple columns is not the correct solution. A common relational database pattern would be to have a Retailers table:

```
[Retailers table]
int RetailerID (primary key)
string Name
```

And an Items table:

```
[Items table]
int ItemID (primary key)
int RetailerID (foreign key)
string Name
int QuantitySold
```

Each item "belongs" to a retailer because of the foreign key relationship. This is a much better design than having a column per item - that's a bad anti-pattern of relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, I would add an id column for each table, which would then allow for a join to be made. For this to work, you would need to edit the existing tables to allow foreign key joins to a new table, say 'products sold', that will link the two other tables together. The amount of sales could then be counted using the 'count' command.